# SharePoint 2016 Cumulative Update steps

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, pnp-powershell, cumulative-update

I was able to install the CU for SH 2016 on each server after running the command `Suspend-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication –Identity “<Search Service Application Name>”` 
Except the APP and Search servers still show Online and when I install the CU I get this message if I need to close the application or not.
Do I miss any another step? Please help.

SharePoint 2016[image: Search1]

[image: Search2]

[image: Search3]

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to this blog for more information about how to install CU and check the steps:

[How to install SharePoint Cumulative Updates in a SharePoint Farm Step by Step](https://blogit.create.pt/miguelisidoro/2019/04/08/how-to-install-sharepoint-cumulative-updates-in-a-sharepoint-farm-step-by-step/)